# Two discrete time random processes taking the same value in the same time period

Tags: probability, random-variables

My question is kind of a basic one, but it confuses me. The answer will be probably very simple.

We have two discrete time random processes $\{X_i\}$ and $\{Y_i\}$, where $X_i \in \{1,2,\dots,K\}$ and $Y_i \in \{1,2,\dots,K,\dots,L\}$ ($L>K$), and $P(X_i=k)=\frac{1}{K}$ and $P(Y_i=k)=\frac{1}{L}, \ \forall k$ and they are i.i.d .

Consider the case that the time scale of the processes are different, i.e., for every time step of $\{X_i\}$, an integer number of steps pass for $\{Y_i\}$. Let $\gamma$ denote this scaling factor.

I will try to clarify the scaling with some illustration for $\gamma=2$.

$\{X_i\}$ : |1111|2222|1111|2222|----|

$\{Y_i\}$ : |11|22|11|22|11|22|11|22|--|--|

So the processes are taking values 1 and 2 alternatingly. A time step of the first process is of size 4 time unit, and a time step of the second process is of 2 time unit. (I know this is counterintuitive to discrete time processes, maybe this is the problem).

What I am trying to find is the probability that both processes have the same value in the same time period. I have for the general case, but I am not sure it is correct: $$1- P(X_i=k,Y_{\gamma i}\neq k,Y_{\gamma i -1 } \neq k,\dots ,Y_{\gamma (i-1)+1} \neq k) = 1- \frac{1}{K}(1-\frac{1}{L})^{\gamma}$$

In fact, I think when $\gamma=1$, this probability becomes $$P(X_i=k,Y_{\gamma i} = k) = \frac{1}{K}\frac{1}{L}$$

which is not the same as the general case.

Can you help me to write a correct formulation for this probability?

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved my problem. The answer is

$$P(\text{none of Y_i's equals to k in that period} |X_i=k)P(X_i=k)=(1-(1-\frac{1}{L})^{\gamma})\frac{1}{K}$$